# How to return the value in total of 12 digits?

Tags: javascript

How do you format the numbers that result in total of 12 digits?

```
12.123 should result 12.1230000000
1234567890.12345 should result 1234567890.12
12 should result 12.0000000000
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: Can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Number.prototype.toPrecision()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/CX7Ej/)</kbd>

```
function FormatMeTo12Digits(num) {
    return num.toPrecision(12);
}

FormatMeTo12Digits(12.345);
```